# convert System.Object[] into csv comma separated object in Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a System.Object[] type variable represented in output as

```
item1
item2
item3
```

and I want to convert it in csv comma separated with same System.Object[] type as

```
"item1","item2","item3"
```

code written as ---->

```
#getting header of CSV
    $firstrow = (Get-Content tabledataformat.csv | Select-Object -First 1)
    #Splitting it to make an array
    $firstrow = $firstrow -split ","
    #Now I iterate over array to compare it with hash key and replace with 
    hash key value incase it matches
    foreach ($item in $firstrow)  {
        $item = $item -replace '"',""
        if ($hash.keys -eq $item)
         {
           # $newrow += $hash['$item']
             $newrow += $hash[$item]
          }
         else {
            $newrow += $item
         }   
     }
#now I make it again back to array
$newrow = $newrow.split(',')
```

and now I want to add this to first row of different csv so I need

"item1","item2","item3" to merge to data in another sheet

Comment: What do you mean by "with same System.Object[] type"? Once you convert your data to text (including CSV), type information is lost. It might also help if you could show how you obtained the values in the first place

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen added my code in description

Comment: You could try `$firstrow = $firstrow -split "," -replace '"'`. Then `Import-Csv otherfile.csv -Header $firstrow | Export-Csv output.csv -NoType`

Comment: @AdminOfThings almost there :) how can I eliminate header of otherfile.csv in Import-Csv otherfile.csv -Header $firstrow | Export-Csv output.csv -NoType as I'm setting new header inline in it?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have two files like below:

```
# file1.csv Contents with header row
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6

# file2.csv Contents without header row
7,8,9
10,11,12

# file3.csv contents with header row
x,y,z
13,14,15
16,17,18
```

You can convert your first CSV into an object and retrieve its properties as an array. Then simply use that array of properties as the `-Header` value when reading the second CSV (via `Import-Csv`).

```
# Add file1.csv headers to file2.csv
$FirstRowAsArray = (Import-Csv file1.csv | Select -First 1).psobject.Properties.Name
$file2 = Import-Csv file2.csv -Header $FirstRowAsArray
$file2 | Export-Csv file2.csv -NoType


# Replace file3.csv headers with file1.csv headers
$FirstRowAsArray = (Import-Csv file1.csv | Select -First 1).psobject.Properties.Name
$file3 = Import-Csv file3.csv -Header $FirstRowAsArray | Select-Object -Skip 1 
$file3 | Export-Csv file3.csv -NoType
```

Another alternative is to read and write text.

```
# Replace file3.csv headers with file1.csv headers
$output = @(Get-Content file1.csv -TotalCount 1)+(Get-Content file3.csv | Select-Object -Skip 1)
$output | Set-Content file3.csv
```

Comment: I actually did Import-Csv tabledataformattedtest33.csv -Header $newrow | select-object -Skip 2 | export-csv newdata.csv -NoType and it worked